# Email program for Mac OS X supporting GMail's inbox categories (Primary, Updates, etc.)?

Tags: osx, email-client

GMail has inbox categories such as Primary/Updates/Promotions. Is there a Mac email program which splits mail by these, e.g. letting you see only the Primary category?